# Returning only one column in json from eloquent relationship using eager loading

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have this in a "Product" model to map the one to many relationship between a product and a barcode:

```
public function barcodes(){
    return $this->hasMany('Barcode', 'productId', 'id')->select(['barcode', 'productId']);
}
```

Next, this code gives me not only the product, but also each barcode in an array of objects.

```
public function search(){
    $results = Product::with('barcodes')->where('name', 'LIKE', 'theQueryString')->get();
    return Response::json($return);
}
```

This is an example output:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Warehouse Box",
            "created_at": "2034-12-14 06:57:52",
            "updated_at": "2064-12-14 06:27:52",
            "barcodes": [
                {
                    "barcode": "0750028400400",
                    "productId": 1
                },
                {
                    "barcode": "123456789",
                    "productId": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of "barcodes" returning an array of objects, I want "barcodes" just to be an array of values.

Said another way, I want to return the value of the "barcode" column in each barcode object instead of the object itself.

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Warehouse Box",
            "created_at": "2034-12-14 06:57:52",
            "updated_at": "2064-12-14 06:27:52",
            "barcodes": [
                "0750028400400",
                "123456789"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a quick and smart way of doing this in Laravel using Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`lists()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) which makes an array containing one property of each model in a collection. However the problem is that we have to do this for every *result* of the relation in the model. That would mean a loop in your controller. (and we don't want that right)

Instead you can override `toArray()` (which will be called when you do `Response::json()`) in your model. In the code below, we override `barcodes` with the `lists()` result.

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['barcodes'] = $this->barcodes->lists('barcode');
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Lovely!  I'm new to Laravel and this solution blew my mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure to the `with` method and specify what columns you want to select using the `select` method:

```
public function search(){
    $results = Product::with(array('barcodes' => function($query) {
        return $query->select('barcode');
    }))->where('name', 'LIKE', 'theQueryString')->get();

    ...
```

and then you can use a `collapse` method provided in the Laravel's Collection class:

```
$results->barcodes = $results->barcodes->collapse();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately this doesn't help much as you must also select the column for the foreign key, in this case, 'productId'.  Good idea but this is the same issue I've been running into.  I will still need to remove the ID column from my barcodes.

Comment: You should try adding the `$visible` property in your Barcode model to define fields that are exported to the JSON/array.